# Is there a way to pd.cut a scalar?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for the equivalent of pd.cut but for a scalar?

I would like to do this:

```
bins = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150]
pd.cut(43, bins=bins)
```

But currently that throws a value error:

```
ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional
```

It can be fixed adding `[]`:

```
pd.cut([43], bins=bins)
```

Which outputs:

```
[(40, 50]]
Categories (10, interval[int64]): [(0, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15] < (15, 20] ... (30, 40] < (40, 50] < (50, 100] < (100, 150]]
```

But just wondering if there is a better way to go from scalar to interval in Python in general or with Pandas?

Comment: The [pandas.cut doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) states that `x` must be array-like and 1-dimensional, so I guess not. `pandas.cut` cannot extrapolate the dimension from a single integer or float. You need to wrap it into a list as you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the associated `Interval` object you can construct an `IntervalIndex` and filter with `get_loc`:

```
In [2]: bins = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150]

In [3]: ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(bins)

In [4]: ii[ii.get_loc(43)]
Out[4]: Interval(40, 50, closed='right')
```